# How to overwrite a csv file. PHP

Tags: php, file, csv

I only started PHP yesterday so forgive me in areas of poor code.

I have a csv file called `employee_data.csv`. It contains employee records formatted like so.

```
JANE WILLIAMS,6/8/1998,55846874E,4323
PETER JONES,15/01/1982,56897547Q,1234
JAMES O'BRIEN,09/05/2001,25689514W,8475
```

The employees are displayed on a form on the browser with each row containing an employee details and a delete button beside each row of the table. When the user selects the delete button beside a given employee, the selected employee gets deleted from the form and the employee_data.csv file and the new form is shown without the deleted employee.

**delete table**

[image]

I want to delete the selected record within the csv file but before I worry about the deleting part I just want to figure out how to overwrite the employee_details.csv with a new employee_details.csv with the same details.

Too achieve this I want to

1.implode the contents of the employee_data.csv file to a string.

2.explode the contents of the string to an array.

3.Delete employee.data.csv 

4.Create a new employee_data.csv file.

5.Write the contents of the array to the new employee_data.csv file

6.Output the employee records in the new file on to a table with each row containing an employee record.

The $group array is an array of objects where each object is an employee record from the employee_data.csv file.

```html
<?php 
$dataFile = fopen("persistence/employee_data.csv", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$i=0;  //index for the array
while(!feof($dataFile)) {
  $csv=fgets($dataFile); //read a line from the CSV file
  if(!feof($dataFile)){ //make sure not at end
   $employeeProperties=explode(",",$csv); //parse values to an array
          
          
        
        $group[$i]=new Employee($employeeProperties[0],$employeeProperties[1],$employeeProperties[2],$employeeProperties[3]);//create new person objects
   $i++;
  } 
}
fclose($dataFile); //close the data file
?>
```

I then imploded the contents of the $group array to a string, and then exploded the string to a string array.

```html
<?php
$str = implode(array_map(function($x) { return $x->get_employeeName() . $x ->get_dob()  
        .$x->get_PPSN() .$x->get_PIN().","; }, $group));
echo $str;   //implode file objects to string

$parts = explode(',' , $str);  //explode to string array
print_r($parts);
?>
```

The contents inside the $str - JANE WILLIAMS6/8/199855846874E4321 ,PETER JONES15/01/198256897547Q1234 ,JAMES O'BRIEN09/05/200125689514W8475

The contents of the array of string $parts Array ( [0] => JANE WILLIAMS6/8/199855846874E4321 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBmyc.png) => PETER JONES15/01/198256897547Q1234 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBmyc.png) => JAMES O'BRIEN09/05/200125689514W8475 [3] => )

I then deleted the orignal employee_data.csv, created a new employee_data.csv and wrote the string array to the csv file.

```html
<?php
$file_Path = 'persistence/employee_data.csv';

if(file_exists($file_Path))
    {
        unlink($file_Path);    //delete file
        echo 'File Deleted';
    }else{
        echo 'File Not Exist';
    }
    
    $csv_handler = fopen ('persistence/employee_data.csv','w'); //new file
    fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
    fclose ($csv_handler);
    
    $filename = 'persistence/employee_data.csv';
   if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $datafile = fopen('persistence/employee_data.csv', 'w'); //write to new file
    fputcsv($datafile, $parts," ",chr(0)); 
    fclose($datafile);
   }
?>
```

This is what I want the contents of the new employee_data.csv file to look like. 

JANE WILLIAMS,6/8/1998,55846874E,4321

PETER JONES,15/01/1982,56897547Q,1234

JAMES O'BRIEN,09/05/2001,25689514W,8475

Instead It looks like.

JANE WILLIAMS6/8/199855846874E4321

 , PETER JONES15/01/198256897547Q1234

 , JAMES O'BRIEN09/05/200125689514W8475

 ,

In the new csv file there are now 4 records, the last one doesnt contain anything and I'm not sure why this gets added. I want to just have a comma after the name,dob and ppsn. The last 4 digits of each record is a pin.

Is there a more effiecient way to overwrite an csv file? Is there any way to achieve what I want to achieve? I've been messing around with the format of the new file for the past hour and thats the best I have come up with so far.

## Note: I have to update any changes made to the csv file in my project so if I delete an employee record from the csv file, I need a new or overwritten csv file without the deleted employee.

Comment: instead of `fgets` use `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv`, using `$parts = explode(',' , $str);` will fail in cases where the data contains a comma and probably with new lines, both of which are properly handled by the built in csv function such as `data,"row with, comma", otherstuff` if you split this with `explode` you get 4 columns, if you use `fgetcsv` you get 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your making this way harder then it needs to be, for example

```
<?php 
$dataSrc = "persistence/employee_data.csv";
$dataDest = "persistence/new_employee_data.csv";

$dataFile = fopen($dataSrc, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$outFile = fopen($dataDest, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$i=0;  //index for the array
while(false !== ($csv = fgetcsv($dataFile))) {
    //$csv = [ANE WILLIAMS,6/8/1998,55846874E,4323];
    //add check to remove row
    if($csv[2] == '55846874E') continue; //skip to next itteration

    fputcsv($outFile, $csv);
}

fclose($dataFile);
fclose($outFile);

//rename($dataDest, $dataSrc); //rename dest to the source name, this will overwrite $dataSrc with $dataDest and remove $dataDest
```

no ending tags, no exploding, no junk.

This should (in theory) take the contents of `$dataFile` write it to `$outFile` line by line, if the 3rd column = `'55846874E'` it will skip writing that line.

For example, by using `rename` we can remove the old file, remove the new file and rename the new file to the old file all in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,I definetly over complicated it! The new file is ceated with out the deleted record formatted perfectly in new_employee_data.csv, however I'm getting an error 

 "fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given at line 24"

which is this line

fputcsv($outFile, $csv);

Comment: Ok, I updated  the while loop. This can happen if there is an empty line at the end of the file.  So the file is not finished,but there is no csv data.  So in this case probably `$csv` is false, so we an just use that in the loop, this way it exits the loop.  Before it goes into the loop, gets the csv data which is `false` then trys to put that in `fputcsv`  which blows up because its a boolean not an array.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm still getting the same error however - fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in line 24. Also the contents in the $csv array is always the second row in the file "PETER JONES",15/01/1982,56897547Q,1234 regardless of whats in the if statment. Therefore "PETER JONES",15/01/1982,56897547Q,1234 is the only one that can get written to the new_employee_data file.

Comment: That's very strange, It's hard to test because obviously I cant open the file, but it should be working like that with the `while` loop, you can see the same sort of setup on the PHP documentation page for it, right here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: One last thing, what OS are you using?  if it's an Mac that can sometimes cause issues with the line endings for the `fgetcsv` function, ususally only on older Mac, it should handle windows and linux just fine as long as there is no weird characters in there ( like curly quotes from MsWord) also make sure you have a single `=` in here `while(false !== ($csv = fgetcsv($dataFile)))` not `$csv ==  fgetcsv( ...)` the single `=` is assignment the double is comparison

Comment: You code is spot on my bad, I had something small wrong in my file. thanks very much!